# How to implement Auto Save in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

While filling out a form, some websites like GMail offer an auto save feature that automatically saves the form filled out so far to the database.

If I have to implement that in my MVC 4 application, how do I do that?

I'm thinking of options but I can't find any other than write some JavaScript code myself to make an Ajax call and send data to the server in JSON format and on the server side, respond by having an action on the controller accept that JSON data, deserialize it and save the incomplete data to the database.

But all this seems like a lot of work. I am assuming there should be an easier way.

Comment: Nope, that's how you do it. Web programming is a lot of work :)

Comment: Thank you. I feared as much. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Sisyphus.js jQuery Autosave plugin](http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/).  It works by saving the form state in LocalStorage, so that the user can retrieve the partially filled-out form.  It has the virtue of not requiring any modifications to the server code, so it should work for *any* existing ASP.NET MVC application.

Download from Github here: https://github.com/simsalabim/sisyphus

Comment: Does it have a method to clear its data out of the local storage because local storage has a 5 MB max storage limit for the entire host.

Comment: Local Storage will be freed of these forms values on submit or reset.